# Uniform continuity of a function given by an integral

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$:$(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as

$$f(x)=\int_0^x \sin^2 t^2\,dt$$

Then how can I prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1)$ and on $\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: I apologize for my typo errors..

Comment: $f$ has a bounded derivative, so it is a Lipschitz function, and consequently, it is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a direct proof, suppose $x,y \geq 0$. We may assume that $y \geq x \geq 0$ (by renaming them if necessary), so
$$\begin{aligned}
|f(y) - f(x)| &= \left|\int_x^y \sin^2 t^2\ dt\right|\\
&\leq \int_x^y|\sin^2 t^2|\ dt \\
&\leq \int_x^y(1)\ dt \\
&= y - x \\
&= |y - x| \\
\end{aligned}$$
Therefore $|y-x| < \epsilon$ implies $|f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bungo..I understand it clearly. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if a function has a bounded derivative, it is uniformly continuous.